# Soap Canonicalization Transform

Tags: java, xml, node.js, web-services, soap

I am trying to work with a soap service hosted on a Datapower appliance. So far, the sending soap service and the receiver calculate the digest differently for the following xml.

The transform that is applied to create the digest value

```
<ds:Reference URI="#TS-f3c103e9-1897-43d8-8cf6-274bdb647678">
    <ds:Transforms>
       <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
          <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="wsse soap"/>
       </ds:Transform>
   </ds:Transforms>
   <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
   <ds:DigestValue>1rjXQQWVMM5KBWY8uswUynk6PCk=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
```

The referenced element.

```
<wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-f3c103e9-1897-43d8-8cf6-274bdb647678">
  <wsu:Created>2016-02-24T15:32:12.693Z</wsu:Created>
  <wsu:Expires>2016-02-24T15:37:12.693Z</wsu:Expires>
</wsu:Timestamp>
```

Namespaces for above elements are applied on the root node

- xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
- xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"

Sending the above XML works correctly (created from a Java soap client library). However, when I digest that same element with sha1 in node, I get a different digest value.

I am trying to discover what java does in the transform before calculating the digest value. If I can figure out what it actually sends to its sha1 method, I can correct the code in node to do the very same.

Given the above reference element, what is the output xml after the transform prior to hashing with sha1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to figure out how your java library or API creates the canonicalized XML that it sends to the SHA1 method.

Using Apache Commons Codec (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) and guessing the C14N'd XML from the Timestamp element and the included namespaces in the Transform element, I was able to get the same digest value: 1rjXQQWVMM5KBWY8uswUynk6PCk=

Here's the code that I used:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;

public class Sha1Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String data = "<wsu:Timestamp xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:wsse=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\" xmlns:wsu=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\" wsu:Id=\"TS-f3c103e9-1897-43d8-8cf6-274bdb647678\"><wsu:Created>2016-02-24T15:32:12.693Z</wsu:Created><wsu:Expires>2016-02-24T15:37:12.693Z</wsu:Expires></wsu:Timestamp>";
        printShaDigest(data);
    }

    static void printShaDigest(String data) {
        System.out.println("data = " + data);
        System.out.println("sha1 = " + new String(Base64.encodeBase64(DigestUtils.sha1(data.getBytes()))));
    }

}
```